# Exceeding Google Sheets API with GSpread

Tags: google-sheets-api, gspread

```
def printit():
  threading.Timer(10.0, printit).start()
  newIDS = wks.acell('A2').value
  inProgIDS = wks.acell('B2').value
  completedIDS = wks.acell('C2').value
  
  
  ticketData = {
            "newIDS" : newIDS,
            "inProgIDS" : inProgIDS,
            "completedIDS" : completedIDS,
  }
  
  with open('ids.json', 'w') as url_file:
    json.dump(ticketData, url_file)

 
printit()
```

I am pinging the Google Api with GSpread every 10 seconds to get some values from a 3 cells. It saids I have exceeded my quota, but when I go to the quota page it states the usage is 17%.

gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:206671335281'.", 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'quota_limit': 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerUser', 'quota_metric': 'sheets.googleapis.com/read_requests', 'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'consumer': 'projects/20}}]}

Answer (score 0):

It's probable you're exceeding your quota. Make sure you're not over [60 requests per minute](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/limits).

The workaround is to implement [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/retry-strategy).

Take more time to make the requests or double check if the file you're reading has other data that require more requests